# flash alert close icon does not float all the way to the right bootstrap/rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get flash alerts in my rails/bootstrap to show with the close icon pulled right all the way. I am using 'close' and 'pull-right' css classes, but the close icon does not go all the way to the right.

[image: screenshot with 0px left and right padding for container-fluid]

In the picture, the black bar is the navbar, and the pink band is the flash alert. The right end of the image is the right end of the page. I want the x close button (pointed by a handdrawn arrow) near the right end of the message, to go much closer to the right end. It does get styled properly and pushed to the right by using the 'close' class, but not all the way. Adding pull-right class does not seem to have any effect.

How do I get the close button to go all the way to the right, ideally flush with the right end of the login link in the navbar?

Update: Here is the code for generating the flash message - note the class on the button is 'close'. Adding 'pull-right' to it makes no difference.

## application_helper.rb

```
def bootstrap_class_for flash_type
  { success: "alert-success", error: "alert-danger", alert: "alert-danger", notice: "alert-info" }[flash_type.to_sym] || flash_type.to_s
end

def flash_messages(opts = {})
  flash.each do |msg_type, message|
  concat(content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert #{bootstrap_class_for(msg_type)} fade in") do 
  concat message
  concat content_tag(:button, raw("&times;"),class: "close", data: { dismiss: 'alert' })
        end)
  end
  nil
end

# application.html.erb

<body>
  <%= render 'layouts/navbar' %>
  <div id="main-container" class="container-fluid">
    <%= flash_messages %>
    ...
  </div>
  ...
</body>

# application.css.scss
.container-fluid {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
```

Update 2: The close icon alignment went bad due to the style in above code, which removed the 15px padding. If I remove that container-fluid style, and leave the 15px padding, I get this whitespace on the edges, which is perhaps, worse (see below image).

[image: screenshot with 15px left and right padding on for container-fluid]

Update 3: When I zero out the container-fluid padding, the nav bar also gets squished *on the left edge*, even if the navbar is rendered ***above*** the container-fluid div. I don't understand why that happens.

Comment: If you do not give any code then no one can help you. By the way, I think (may be) you have right padding that's why you can't push cross button to right.

Comment: You need to show your code sample so you get some help.
It looks like that outer container of Close button has padding so remove it.
Or you can set margin-right at Close button to some negative value like 'margin-right:-50px'

Comment: I realized that this problem happened because, to get rid of the whitespace on the sides of the alert, I had removed the default 15px left and right padding from container-fluid by setting padding-left: 0px and padding-right: 0px. Allowing the padding to remain 15px fixed the close icon, but left the whitespace on the ends of the container on. I am adding another screenshot and these details to the question.

Comment: add a 'row' class to flash alert container 
'alert fade in row'

Comment: That did it, @QaisarNadeem, thanks ! It makes sense too, now you mention it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.alert.fade.in{
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
```

Alternatively you can add `row` class to your alert container like.

```
def flash_messages(opts = {})
  flash.each do |msg_type, message|
  concat(content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert #{bootstrap_class_for(msg_type)} fade in row") do 
  concat message
  concat content_tag(:button, raw("&times;"),class: "close", data: { dismiss: 'alert' })
        end)
  end
  nil
end
```